# Can Thor's Stormbreaker break Captain America's Shield?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, captain-america

Captain America's shield is supposed to be made out of the hardest metal on Earth and that triggers my doubt as to whether Stormbreaker can break it.

Can Thor's Stormbreaker break Captain America's Shield?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Li1t6jPn3Yo

Comment: This feels like an issue of [Gorilla VS Shark](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/). It pretty much comes down to whoever the writer wants to win.

Comment: @Virusbomb This _is not_ GvS under our policy of it as both items are set within the same universe. In fact we can make a decent educated guess as to the answer here.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - It feels opinion-based. They haven't come into conflict, so any guess is going be just that, a guess.

Comment: @Valorum We don't know or educated guesses are fine as answers. Just because it hasn't happened doesn't mean it should be closed.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Given that this is a weapon that's explicitly stronger than Mjolnir, it's very hard to gauge how it stacks up against the shield.

Comment: Given that this is MCU specific, and Cap's shield is not made of Proto-admantium in the MCU, and Stormbreakers capabilities not being fully shown, and the shields failure point not being established, and Thor's recent power increase, and that these all differ from comic continuity, so we cannot attempt to source from there, and the lack of data-points to draw an independent conclusion.... I don't see how this could be anything but opinion-based.

Comment: Even though this is opinion based, this is a genuine doubt. right? I don't think that the action to hold the question should not have been approved by the community authority.

Comment: "we don't know" is an answer, not a reason to close.

Comment: Not a mod, but I think the excerpt from the close reason: "answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise" pretty succinctly covers it. Using our existing answers (and comment chains) as an example: 2 opposite conclusions drawn with very little evidence (and most of that is suspect and circumstantial). Yes, "We don't know" *is* an answer, "Well, this wins because I think it's cooler" is not, and that's the type of answers this question is drawing.

Comment: FWIW, (and spoiler alert I guess) we did see that shield get shredded to pieces by Thanos' sword in Endgame, so strongest metal on earth is not strongest metal anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

## Probably not

Remember in *The Avengers* when Thor hits Cap's shield with Mjölnir and doesn't harm the shield at all.

[image: Thor hits Cap's shield with Mjölnir]

I think we then see them use this technique to fight the bad guys in the opening sequence of *Avengers: Age of Ultron*.

Seeing as Mjölnir and Stormbreaker are both made out of Uru it seems likely they would both have the same effects and as such Stormbreaker would not be able to break the shield on its own.

However, it is worth noting that Stormbreaker is more powerful than Mjölnir in that it can summon the Bifrost and is *"The Thanos killing kind"* but I don't think it's that more powerful **on its own** that it would be able to destroy the shield.

Comment: I wonder how Thor "leveling up" and Stormbreaker having the power of Bifrost would effect this...

Comment: @Skooba Thor's power shouldn't affect the Q/A here as this seems to be solely about Stormbreaker's power on its own (at least that's how I read it). The Bifrost point is quite a good one though but again I wouldn't have thought it would effect it too much.

Comment: In the non-MCU continuity, Uru, especially enchanted Uru is more resilient than Vibranium/Adamantium. The only items of similar durability are Adamantine (such as Hercules mace). This is one of the reasons  MCU and comic universes differ on several points already, so this may be irrelevant, but it seemed worth a mention.  MCU Specific: Stormbreaker is a more powerful weapon than Mjolnir, and vibranium has lost it's "totally indestructible" status, Visions vibranium body has been damaged at the hands of Corvus, Wanda, and Thanos.

Comment: While Stormbreaker and Mjolnir were made of the same metal, that's not really the source of their power. They have built-in enchantments meant to enhance the wielders power. When Eitri makes SB, he himself says "A king's weapon. Meant to be the greatest in Asgard". Considering that he was the guy that made Mjolnir, it's a very easy deduction that SB is definitely more powerful than Mjolnir.

Answer (score 1):

**Very easily, yes.**

Whilst the comparison against Mjolnir is existent, it is no longer valid.

Mjolnir was the equivalent of training wheels compared to the Stormbreaker, which is essentially a hyper-car.

Stormbreaker is a King's weapon. We have seen the kind of feats Odin achieved with Gungnir.

When describing it to thor, Eitri himself says:

> A king's weapon. Meant to be the greatest in Asgard.

Considering that Eitri is the same person who made Mjolnir as well, it's a fairly straight forward deduction that Stormbreaker is without a doubt way more powerful than Mjolnir.

**And we saw how Thor managed to go against a fully powered Infinity gauntlet with the Stormbreaker.**

Cap's shield is the equivalent of toast(literally and figuratively) compared to the infinity gauntlet.

This question may seem like Gorilla vs Shark, but it's actually more like tiger vs a koala.

Can we, in good conscience, claim that Cap's shield: A piece of un-enchanted metal, is stronger than an energy beam generated by the infinity gauntlet harnessing the power of all 6 infinity stones? **No**.

Now since there's no way cap's shield is more powerful than that, and considering we DID actually see Stormbreaker defeat that beam, it is a simple mathematical deduction that Stormbreaker can defeat the shield. It's as simple as A > B, B > C, hence A > C.

This is far from opinion based.

Comment: _"And we saw how Thor managed to go against a fully powered Infinity gauntlet with the Stormbreaker."_ This point is mostly irrelevant, Thor was able to hurt Thanos because he caught him by surprise before Thanos could react not because Stormbreaker overcame the power of the Infinity Stones/Gauntlet.

Comment: [citation needed]

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Thanos shoots a ray out of the gauntlet which Stormbreaker continues to churn through as though it were nothing. Stormbreaker *does* go up against an attack from the empowered gauntlet, and appears to win. https://gfycat.com/appropriateaggressivecanary

Comment: @AAlig I really need to rewatch the film apparently! Although that is Stormbreaker + Thor’s power against the Gauntlet so its not necessarily that Stormbreaker itself is more powerful.

Comment: You make decent comparisons and conjectures in my opinion, but that is just it. All of this still seems to be just your opinion. We really don't know what will happen if the one hits the other unless it has happened in the comics at some point. And it is also worth noting that Thor did put some extra 'umpf' into his axe before his throw. We see lightning crackling all around it as it flies. Given what information we have from the film I could easily say without that amplification from Thor the axe would never have reached Thanos...

Comment: @Odin1806 - sorry to say, but most of what I mentioned aren't opinions. We did see all of those things in the respective films. It would've been an opinion if we hadn't seen stormbreaker go up against the infinity beam (Patent pending :P )

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot caught by surprise or not, Thanos did shoot a powerful beam at Thor, and the Stormbreaker *did* cleave through it like it were butter. And managed to impale Thanos at the same time. I'd say it would have to be pretty damn powerful to manage both.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot if Thor's power is also in the picture, then Thor is definitely way more powerful than he was in Avengers. That lends even more credibility to the notion that Thor, using Stormbreaker, could chop the shield like an onion.

Comment: @Stark07 - Nothing that you say above is 100% MCU verifiable fact except that Stormbreaker is a king's weapon. Sure it is more powerful than Mjolnir, but by how much? 10? 500? Maybe its not a hyper-car increase and more of a dirt bike. And the question is also about the axe, not Thor using the axe. Thor's added power does not count. Can the axe break the shield, not Thor using the axe break the shield. Also, Thor's axe never touched the gauntlet. It hit Thanos in the chest. We don't know what would have happened if it hit the gauntlet. And dont get me started on literal and figurative toast...

Comment: So essentially the point you are making is that Cap's shield can be more powerful than the combined output of 6 infinity stones. Wow. Do you have any facts to back that claim @Odin1806 ? :P :D

Comment: No, the claims I am making are: 1. Stormbreaker never touched the gauntlet, only the blast that came from it. 2. Stormbreaker was additionally charged by Thor during said attack. 3. The only items that have interacted are Mjolinr and the Shield and they were evenly matched, or even slight advantage to the shield as everyone but Cap was thrown back. 4. We can only guess what will happen between a match of Stormbreaker and Cap's shield as they have never interacted, even in comics as far as I recall. 5. Any beyond these are speculation and conjecture without verifiable fact to back it up.

Comment: Yes, but saying that "we don't know if Stormbreaker could break cap's shield" despite what we have seen Thor + SB do so far, is essentially saying that "cap's shield could very well be stronger than an energy beam generated by 6 infinity stones". It's a corollary.

Comment: Think of it in terms of mathematics. A > B, B > C, hence A > C. T+SB > IG beam. IG beam definitely > Cap's shield. Hence, T+SB > Cap's shield.
Even if we refute all evidence suggesting T+SB > IG beam, we can surely not even entertain the notion that cap's shield could be stronger than the power of the infinity stones combined.

Comment: "IG beam definitely > Cap's shield" Was this shown?

Comment: I think one also has to consider the type of attack. Magical Beam of Energy which could slowly chip away the shield or simply melt it vs Physical Impact of "Axe on Shield". I would THINK, that the Axe wins, because it has a sharp edge and can put way more pressure on the point of impact, compared to the hammer which was blunt...